# Optional regular expression segment, but list of requirements if present?

Tags: php, regex

I have a small routing engine in PHP. I'm trying to allow it to optionally match different "formats", such as requests to "/user/profile.json" or "/user/profile.xml". However, it should also match just a plain "/user/profile".

So, **if** if the format is present, it must be ".json" or ".xml". But it isn't **required** to be present at all.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#^GET /something/([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_]+)(\.(html|json))?$#
```

Obviously, this doesn't work. This allows any "format" to be requested since the entire format segment is optional. How can I keep it optional, but constrain the formats that can be requested?

Comment: Why don't you just remove the `?` and thus enforce that the format has to be present? The other cases you mentioned to be allowed as well are not covered by this expression anyway.

Comment: I fail to see the problem. This regex matches `/user/profile`, `/user/profile.xml` and `/user/profile.json`, and it doesn't match anything else.

Comment: @TimPietzcker for some reason, i'm able to get a request to "/user/profile.csv" to pass this regex.

Comment: Then the error is somewhere else. Please show the code you're using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^GET /something/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)(\.(html|json))?$
```

allows dots in the first character class, so any file extension is legal. I expect you did that on purpose so filenames with dots in them are possible.

However, this means that if a filename contains a dot, it must end in either `.html` or `.json`. Right?

So change the regex to (using the `\w` shorthand for `[A-Za-z0-9_]`):

```
^GET /something/([\w.-]+\.(html|json)|[\w-]+)$
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative suggestion:

Instead of putting the desired output format into the URL, have the client specify it via the [Accept Header in the HTTP Request](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) (where it belongs). [Content negotiation](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Content_negotiation) is baked into the HTTP protocol, so you do not have to reinvent it via URLs. Technically, it is wrong to put the format into the URL. Your URIs should point to the resource itself and not the resource representation.

Also see [W3C: Content Negotiation: why it is useful, and how to make it work](http://www.w3.org/QA/2006/02/content_negotiation.html)

Comment: While this is true, if you're implementing an API, it's much more convenient for users of the API to specify the format in the URL.

Comment: @Michael i wouldnt say so. To fetch a URL you need an http client anyway. And those available in PHP make it dirt easy to provide extra headers. The only situation where it is inconvenient is when you cannot control the http client's headers.

Comment: `$data = file_get_contents(API_URL)` vs `$ch=curl_init(API_URL); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_HEADER, array('Accept: application/json')); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); $data = curl_exec($ch);`

Comment: Not saying it's challenging or particularly complicated, but the convenience of being able to easily make ad-hoc requests without needing to set any options is nice.

Comment: @Michael you dont need cURL to specify headers though. Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php#example-2070. You could even set a global default context once and then each subsequent call to file_get_contents would use your settings.

Comment: Sure. I think it all comes down to a matter of taste. For example, Twitter uses file extensions in their API to specify return types. I find this convenient because I can test in my browser even if specifying an `Accept` header is perhaps more standards-compliant.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're getting is arising from the fact that most extensions are alpha numeric, yet in your regex you're allowing a dot and characters:

```
#^GET /something/[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_]+(\.(html|json))?$#
```

The section of problem being `[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_]+`.  For the example of the .csv making it though is because it's still matching that character range.

If something has dots in it's file name, then by default, it has a file extension (intentional or unintentional).  The file `My.Finance.Documents` has the extension ".Documents" even though you'd assume it to be a text file or something else.

I hate doing it, but I think you might want to have a larger conditional in your regex, something along the lines of (this is an example, I haven't tested it):

```
#^GET /something/([^\.]+|.*\.(?:html|json))$#
```

Basically, if the file name has not dots in it, it's ok.  If it does have a dot in it (which guarantees it has an extension), it *must* end with .html or .json.